# Apache Camel with Json Array split

Tags: json, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have a camel application which receives a json array request from a jms queue upto size 13000,the structure of the json array request is as below. I would like to stream and split the json array with a group of 5.
For example if I receive a json array of size 100 I would like to group as 5 and split it as 20 requests.
Is there a inbuilt camel functionality to group and split json array or do I need to write a custom splitter?

I'm using camel 2.17 version.

Sample json array:

```
[{
    "name": "Ram",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "age": 23
 }, {
    "name": "Shyam",
    "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
    "age": 28
 }, {
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "age": 33
 }, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "email": "bob32@gmail.com",
    "age": 41
 }, {
    "name": "test1",
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "age": 41
 }, {
    "name": "test2",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "age": 41
 }, {
    "name": "test3",
    "email": "test3@gmail.com",
    "age": 41
 }, {
    "name": "test4",
    "email": "test4@gmail.com",
    "age": 41
}]
```

Comment: does this json array come as one message in the queue? And do you mean you want to split it into multiple jms messages?

Comment: Hi Kiran,yes we get single jms json array message and we need to split in to multiple messages.

Answer (score 10):

You could try something like this:

```
@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                .split().jsonpath("$")
                    .streaming()
                    .aggregate(AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())
                    .constant("true")
                    .completionSize(5)
                    .completionTimeout(1000)
                    .log("${body}")
                .to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}
```

If the message doesn't have a size multiple of five, the route should wait 1 sec before aggregating and go ahead. Using your input, the result will be two messages with 5 and 3 items respectively:

```
INFO 5419 --- [           main] route1                                   : List<Exchange>(5 elements)
INFO 5419 --- [eTimeoutChecker] route1                                   : List<Exchange>(3 elements)
```

A full sample could be viewed [in here](https://github.com/ricardozanini/camel-labs/blob/master/src/test/java/com/stackoverflow/camel/labs/json/JsonArraySplitRouterTest.java).

EDIT:

As requested, a Spring DSL example:

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="direct:start" />
    <camel:split streaming="true">
        <camel:jsonpath>$</camel:jsonpath>
        <camel:aggregate completionSize="5"
            completionTimeout="1000" groupExchanges="true">
            <camel:correlationExpression>
                <camel:constant>true</camel:constant>
            </camel:correlationExpression>
            <camel:log message="${body}"></camel:log>
            <camel:to uri="mock:result"></camel:to>
        </camel:aggregate>
    </camel:split>
</camel:route>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo i already tried the same,in our case we need to split a json array of 20000 to a completionsize of 20 does the completionTimeout 1000 ms holds good or do i need to revisit the value?

Comment: I think you should run some load tests to assert this value. 1000 ms is a magic number, though. :)

Comment: Hi Ricardo,Iam able to split the json message to List<Exchange>(elements) how can i convert it in to json string in camel?i have done <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/> but it doesnt work

Comment: You could implement your own aggregate strategy and concat each message into a string builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from("{{queue.endpoint}}")
.split().tokenize("},", 5)
.log("Incoming request : ${body} ")
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem not long ago. I had a JSON array containing over 2000 items and I needed to send it to a REST Service via PUT.

I'm using a later version of camel though, 3.17.0. This is what my pipeline looks like.

```
    from("direct-vm:someRoute")
            .process(new ListObjectCreator())
            .split(body())
            .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
            .completionSize(100)
            .completionTimeout(1000)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .log("${body}")
            .to("direct:updateAPI")
    ;
```

What's going on here is that in my **process** the body is read from the current Exchange and adds it to POJOs in an ArrayList.

Then the body in the pipeline is **split**, which is splitted into single POJO objects.

The **aggregate** groups the splitted body into a list of objects.

With **completionSize(100)** the aggregation of each list should only consist of 100 objects.

With **completionTimeout(1000)** the aggregation to waits 1 second before each aggregation completes.

**Marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)** converts the list of objects to JSON. Since it's a list the JSON will be an array of 100 or less objects.

**Log("${body}")**, well, just logging the result which should be one log line per list/array.

Then the messages are routed to another pipeline that handles the headers and functions related to the REST call.

Hope this can be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
@Autowired
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct://splitted-queue")
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@Component
  class Router extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("direct://direct-queue").split(ExpressionBuilder.languageExpression("jsonpath","$")).convertBodyTo(String.class).process(new Processor() {
        List<String> jsons = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          jsons.add(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
          if(jsons.size() == 5) {
            producerTemplate.sendBody(jsons);
            jsons.clear();
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

You need camel-jsonpath dependency for this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The above is a camel route.. what do you mean?

Comment: Dear Kiran, I meant Spring DSL.

Comment: why don't you give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JSONArraySplitterBean {

 public static List<JSONObject> convertToListOfJsonObjects(String input) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(input);
        return arrayToStream(array).parallel().map(JSONObject.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Then in your route:

```
private JSONArraySplitterBean myFunkySplitterBean = new JSONArraySplitterBean();

    from("bla")
    .split().method(myFunkySplitterBean, "convertToListOfJsonObjects")
    .to("bla2");
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is old: the question has been asked 5 years and 15 days ago, but as I don't like to let a question unanswered, I am trying to here.

> Camel 2.17: The collate function iterates the message body and groups the data into sub lists of specified size. This can be used with the Splitter EIP to split a message body and group/batch the splitted sub message into a group of N sub lists. This method works similar to the collate method in Groovy.

How to use it:

```
<split ...>
    <!-- supposed an ArrayList of Json  -->        
    <simple>${collate(3)}</simple>
    
    <log message="Splited Body: ${body}" />
    <log message="Split dataSplitIndex: ${headers.dataSplitIndex}, isLast: ${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitComplete}" />
    
</split>
```